# iPhone 5 e iOS 8 - Permissões de localização

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

Em todos os dispositivos está OK, aparece a requisição de permissão para o uso da localização (independente iOS 7 ou iOS 8). Apenas no iPhone 5 não aparece.

Código de requisição de permissão:

```
var versionString = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil) as NSString
    if versionString.floatValue >= 800 {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized && CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {

            if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied {
                    NSLog("Not Accepted")
            } else {
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            }
        }
    } else {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied {
            NSLog("Not Accepted")
        } else {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
```

Declarei a chave NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription "Precisamos de sua localização"

Comment: iPhone 5 com iOS 8 ou 7? Seu acesso à localização é negado? Veja também se seu app já está listado em `Ajustes > Privacidade > [Nome do seu app]`

Comment: Ele não está listado, e não mostra o diálogo para requisição de permissão.

Comment: Mas é iOS 8? Seu acesso é negado?

Comment: é iOS 8. No iOS 8 e 7 ele efetua a requisição de permissão, apenas no iPhone 5. No iPad, e no 6 ele efetua a pergunta.

Comment: Você já adicionou a chave `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` no seu Info.plist?

Comment: Sim, adicionei: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription como tipo Boolean com valor true

Comment: `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` deve ser um valor `String`. Essa descrição aparecerá para o usuário na hora que a permissão for requisitada.

Comment: Certo, apenas essa chave? nenhuma mais?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na minha resposta e vê se te ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No iOS 8, antes de poder usar o CoreLocation você deve chamar a função `requestAlwaysAuthorization`para uso em primeiro plano ou `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` para uso em segundo plano.

Como estas funções só estão disponíveis a partir do iOS 8, se você chamar alguma delas diretamente no iOS 7 seu app irá morrer com um erro de `unrecognized selector`.

Você deve chamar da seguinte forma:

*Trocar `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` por `requestAlwaysAuthorization` caso esteja pedindo permissão para uso no background.*

**Swift:**

```
if (locationManager.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization"))) {
  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
  [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

Deve também adicionar as seguintes chaves no `Info.plist` do seu projeto:

**Para uso em primeiro plano:**

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Mensagem que o usuário verá na janela de permissão</string>
```

**Para uso em segundo plano**

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Mensagem que o usuário verá na janela de permissão</string>
```

Caso não adicione estas chaves acontece exatamente o que você está descrevendo: não aparece nada.